# jquery validate, adding a new rule to check email host

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to create a rule that checks is the email host is Hotmail so I can show a message asking to check their spam folder (most of my messages go to that folder when people use Hotmail).

Here's what I've done so far:

```
       jQuery.validator.addMethod("isHotmail", function(value, element) {
           var email = $("#email").val();
           var emailHost = email.split('@')[1].split('.')[0];
           if(emailHost=='hotmail'){return true}
}, "* you are using Hotmail, please check your spam folder");
```

And

```
 rules: {
         email: {
           required:true, email: true, isHotmail : true
         }
.
.
```

This is not working, nothing happens if I enter a Hotmail email address,  and I suspect that it is because of the return statement.

Can anyone please give me a hand with this rule?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return false when the input contains 'hotmail'. So instead of

```
if(emailHost=='hotmail'){return true}
```

use

```
if(emailHost=='hotmail')
{
return false;
}
return true; //for when the input does not contain hotmail
```

See it in action on [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/robasta/GMcQq/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to `return false;` if it isn't a hotmail?

try to change line: `if(emailHost=='hotmail'){return true}`

To:

```
return (emailHost.toLowerCase()=="hotmail");
```

`var email` isn't is the same as `value`?

---

```
   jQuery.validator.addMethod("isHotmail", function(value, element) {
       var email = value;
       var emailHost = email.split('@')[1].split('.')[0];
       return (emailHost.toLowerCase()=='hotmail');
   }, "* you are using Hotmail, please check your spam folder");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but if I use your code or if I return false with mine, it shows "* you are using Hotmail, please check your spam folder" even when I enter an email host that is not Hotmail ...

Comment: ok so the validator shows the text if the function returns false; Then do: `return (emailHost.toLowerCase()!='hotmail');`